# Activity is waiting until service is finished

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a strange problem. I have an Activity with a ListView and start a service in the Activity in onCreate.

When I start the App now the Layout of the Activity is not shown until the service has done his work. =( Normaly the service should do his work in the background.

Activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class DealAlertMainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        //start service if its not running
        if(isMyServiceRunning() == false)
            startService(new Intent(DealAlertMainActivity.this, DealAlert_Service.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("keyword", "Test Keyword");
        map.put("title", "Test Title");
        mylist.add(map);
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("keyword", "Test Keyword 2");
        map.put("title", "Test Title 2");
        mylist.add(map);

        SimpleAdapter feeds_list = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.listview_item,
                    new String[] {"keyword", "title"}, new int[] {R.id.Keyword, R.id.Title});
        list.setAdapter(feeds_list);

    }

...

}
```

Service

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;


public class DealAlert_Service extends Service {

    private NotificationManager mNM;

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }





    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //Do work

        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are automatically in the background from a UI standpoint. They are *not* automatically in the background from a threading standpoint. `onStartCommand()` is called on the main application thread, and your UI will be frozen for however long `onStartCommand()` takes to complete. Hence, any significant work to be done by the service needs to be done in a background thread, whether it is one you create yourself or one you get by switching to `IntentService`.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I've got another app, where I used the same code and it works well. :O So where should I use the background Thread? In the Acitvity or in the service, what you htink it's better?

Comment: @Stefan: "Are you sure?" -- yes. "Because I've got another app, where I used the same code and it works well." -- the work you are doing there in `onStartCommand()` is either quick or uses a background thread. "In the Acitvity or in the service, what you htink it's better?" -- I have no way to answer that, sorry.